# how to show popup notification when android device screen off

Tags: android, json, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I will try to send data messages to my application like this format.

```
    {
       "to": "token",
       "data": {
           "title":"Title...",
           "body":"Body...",
           "text":"text"
       }
    }
```

Then after this JSON I am getting in my device with below method.

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Map<String, String> map = message.getData();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
            String key = o.toString();
            String value = map.get(key);
            obj.put(key, value);
        }

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Test ...", obj.toString(), resultIntent);

    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title,
                                    String message,
                                    Intent intent) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message) && TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        return;
    }

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);


    notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    showSmallNotification(title, message, resultPendingIntent, notificationSoundUri);
    playNotificationSound();
}

private void showSmallNotification(String title,
                                   String message,
                                   PendingIntent resultPendingIntent,
                                   Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;

    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(10000), notification);
}
```

That time using this title and body I want to show notification popup form my device and my device screen off so how I can popup notification in my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  /Just implement one line/

.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)

 /******************************/

  notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setTicker(title)
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .setContentText(message)
        .build();


/**Implement below Method***/

/**And call for "wakeUpLock" Method inside onMessageReceived()**/

private void wakeUpLock()
{


    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)MyGcmListenerService.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

    Log.i(TAG, "screen on: "+ isScreenOn);

    if(isScreenOn==false)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "screen on if: "+ isScreenOn);

        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");

        wl.acquire(10000);

        PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");

        wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    }


}
```

Comment: this is valid ans but working below marshmallow you have any suggestion for above marshmallow